# Editing terrain in Blender

Tags: blender, terrain

I have created a terrain mesh in World Machine. When editing the mesh in Blender is it possible to select a vertex and adjust its coordinates using text entry? I need the height of each vertex to be an integer multiple of 24, and the horizontal distance between adjacent vertices to be integer multiples of 32. Using the mouse to drag things around is much too imprecise. Thanks.

Comment: This looks like a good question to search for on the Blender StackExchange instead — they have [existing answers](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/135525) covering [similar ground](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/111063).